# Strategy to snapshot large data set Oracle

Tags: oracle, data-modeling, datamodel

### My Problem:

I have an app and users who login have a department authorization list:

```
DEPT1, DEPT2, DEPT3, ..., DEPT5000, DEPT5001, ...
```

Most users have 5,000+ departments assigned to their profile.

I am tasked with writing a data model + application code that will 'snapshot' their list of authorized departments every time a user logs in so that we may refer to what that user was authorized to do (note: the DEPT IDs are not neatly numbered like in this example).

### What I've tried:

My first thought was to turn the list of departments into a long CSV string and store it as a CLOB:

```
CREATE TABLE UI_SECURITY_CONFIG (
    SECURITY_CONFIG_ID NUMBER(19,0) NOT NULL,
    DEPTSCSV CLOB NOT NULL
);
```

And each `DEPTSCSV CLOB` would be unique. If the user has the same security profile as someone else who's logged in previously, it would just select that security config. Otherwise, it would create a new row. Basically, do a select where DEPTSCSV = 'DEPT1, DEPT2, DEPT3 ...' and if it doesn't exist, insert it. But this approach failed because a huge string that big (25,000+ chars) isn't comparable:

```
SELECT * FROM UI_SECURITY_CONFIG WHERE DEPTSCSV = 'DEPT0001, DEPT0002, DEPT0003, ..., DEPT5001, DEPT5002'

SQL Error [1704] [42000]: ORA-01704: string literal too long
```

### Solution attempt #2:

So then I thought about making each item in the CSV its own row in the table:

```
CREATE TABLE UI_SECURITY_CONFIG (
    SECURITY_CONFIG_ID NUMBER(19,0) NOT NULL,
    DEPTID VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO UI_SECURITY_CONFIG(SECURITY_CONFIG_ID, DEPTID) VALUES(1, 'DEPT0001');
INSERT INTO UI_SECURITY_CONFIG(SECURITY_CONFIG_ID, DEPTID) VALUES(1, 'DEPT0002');
INSERT INTO UI_SECURITY_CONFIG(SECURITY_CONFIG_ID, DEPTID) VALUES(1, 'DEPT0003');
...
INSERT INTO UI_SECURITY_CONFIG(SECURITY_CONFIG_ID, DEPTID) VALUES(1, 'DEPT5001');
INSERT INTO UI_SECURITY_CONFIG(SECURITY_CONFIG_ID, DEPTID) VALUES(1, 'DEPT5002');
```

But I'm struggling to write the SQL select that would be an efficient matching algorithm to find if a SECURITY_CONFIG_ID exists that matches exactly the list of Departments.

I'm not even sure there is an efficient way to solve this problem.

### Solution Attempt #3:

Ask Stack Overflow. What would you do?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve strategy #1. The Application code (Java) handled the CLOB comparison better than my SQL client (DBeaver) with PreparedStatement:

```
String sql = "SELECT SECURITY_CONFIG_ID FROM UI_SECURITY_CONFIG WHERE dbms_lob.compare(DEPTSCSV, ?) = 0";

String DEPTSCSV = "DEPT0001, DEPT0002, ...";

try(PreparedStatement objStmt = objConn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
    Clob clob1 = objConn.createClob();
    clob1.setString(1, DEPTSCSV);
    objStmt.setClob(1, clob1);

    ResultSet result = objStmt.executeQuery();
    ...
}
```